# spool with correct format

Tags: sql, oracle, unix, spool

I have a `sql` file in with the below mentioned and when i execute it from `sqlplus` it is not printing the column names also the select output is printing in more than one line.

```
SET head OFF;
SET feedback OFF
SET verify OFF
SET echo OFF
SET termout OFF
SET colsep '|'
SET LINES 5000
SET LINESIZE 5000
SET PAGES 0
SET PAGESIZE 5000
SET TRIMSPOOL ON

SELECT '1 -- Validating emp entries ' from dual;

SELECT 'SELECT emp_name,emp_no,manager
  FROM emp;' FROM DUAL;

SELECT 'EXPECTED VALUE = 1 from emp' from dual;

SELECT 'Actual count from emp'||' = '||count(*)
  FROM emp;

SELECT emp_name,emp_no,manager
  FROM emp;
```

Can someone help me to print the output as mentioned below

```
1 -- Validating emp entries

SELECT *
 FROM emp;

EXPECTED VALUE = 1 from emp

Actual count from emp = 1

EMP_NAME     |EMP_NO |MANAGER

--------      ------  -------

Thomas Albert|12     |SAM
```

Even though the column width is more it should fit with in max value for  the column.

Comment: I don't understand the last sentence. Could you explain it, perhaps by editing your message and posting what you get now, and what you'd want to get as the final result?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the spaces closed up, so that

```
EMP_NAME     |EMP_NO |MANAGER
--------      ------  -------
Thomas Albert|12     |SAM
```

becomes

```
EMP_NAME|EMP_NO|MANAGER
Thomas Albert|12|SAM
```

in SQL*Plus 12.2 you can [`set markup csv`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqpug/starting-SQL-Plus.html#GUID-B3B93959-2119-447D-A9D3-2349DDD70435), or SQL Developer has something similar.

If you can't use those, you'll have to write your own parser. Here's mine:
http://www.williamrobertson.net/documents/refcursor-to-csv.shtml.